# How do I create the IF Statement in Excel which can handle many conditions. My Example provided

Tags: excel, if-statement, excel-formula

As you can see in my picture.
There is a table to the right.

1. Cell D3 has the option to select 90.0, 95.0, 99.0, and 99.9
2. Cell D4 is a % value
3. Cell D5 I have:   `IF(AND(D3=90,3/D4<9),3,4)`  Obviously if the user selects 90 for D3, then I want to determine which 2 X choices either 3 or 4 from the table are used based on the value of Y which I get by the 3/D4.  This statement is working 100% correct.

MY QUESTION, How do I add the other parts of the table to this same line of code for when D3 = 95, 99, and 99.9?

I try this:  `=IF(OR(AND(D3=90, 3/D4<9),3,4, IF(AND(D3=95,4/D4<16),4,5)))`

[image: Excel Image]

Comment: Do you want to get values from column H into D5?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
=CHOOSE(MATCH(D3,{90,95,99,99.9},0),
    IF(3/D4>= 9, 4,IF(3/D4>= 5,3,NA())),
    IF(3/D4>=16, 5,IF(3/D4>= 7,4,NA())),
    IF(3/D4>=20, 7,IF(3/D4>= 7,6,IF(3/D4>=6,5,NA()))),
    IF(3/D4>=32,10,IF(3/D4>=15,9,IF(3/D4>=9,8,IF(3/D4>=8,7,NA()))))
)
```

In this formula `MATCH(D3,{90,95,99,99.9},0)` will return 1, 2, 3, or 4. This is used by `CHOOSE` to select the login in one of the four lines below.

Each of the next four lines is a nested `IF` statements. The question as asked has integer thresholds for `3/D4` and is a little ambiguous about things that fall in the gaps: for example, how do you handle `C=90` and `3/D4=8.5`. I've made the decision/assumption that when  `3/D4<9`, return `3`. If that's wrong (for instance you want to round `3/D4` to an integer) you can modify the formula accordingly.

I've also made the decision to return `NA` when `3/D4` is below the lowest threshold. You can modify the formula to change that behavior too.